# Move forked repo to another project in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

As part of a new development work I have a git repo that is forked in Azure DevOps. Instead of forking the repo into a new project it is forked into the same project.
I want to know if it is possible to move the forked repo into a new Azure DevOps project with keeping the link to the original repo.

This is because there are already changes made to the forked one and we do not want to loose this, but we also want to be able to merge changes between the repos.

A clone does not work, because then the link is gone and forking the fork puts an extra step in between when wanting to merge commits between the repos.

Comment: Hi @Marco, You could try jessehouwing answer and kindly share the result here, If this answer is helpful, you could feel free to accept it as the answer. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do here:

1. Fork the original repository again to a the desired project.
2. `git clone --mirror` the old forked repo.
3. `git push --mirror` the push to the new forked repo (if needed with `--force`)

This will move over the contents of the old forked git repo to the new project and the fork relationship will already be there.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do this, we could fork the repo to another project and move repo to another project via clone URL and import feature, but we cannot move the fork repo to another project and protect the fork relationship.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @jessehouwing did not work for me, but very similar instructions did work. I can clearly explain them here to help others in the same situation.

---

1. Create a new fork into the new project from the original (upstream / base) repository. Now the new project has a forked repository as wanted, but it is not yet up to date with the other old fork.

For example.

[Select Fork Option on Original Repository]

Go to the original project in Azure DevOps, select the original repository, select the Fork option in the menu (in the 3 dots menu next to the clone button at time of writing).

[Choose the New Target Project and Fork Name]

Give the fork repository the desired name (same as the existing fork I assume, this is what I did at least and that works). Select the new target Project from the drop down. Create fork.

---

2. Update the new fork with the old fork to be moved.

I followed GitHub Docs instructions on how to mirror a repository for this:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository?platform=linux#mirroring-a-repository

For example.

Go to a terminal from where you can access your repository.

Find a directory where you can cleanly check out the repository.

Now run:

```
git clone --bare git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/org/old_project/fork_repo_name
```

Navigate into the new directory:

```
cd fork_repo_name.git
```

Now push to the new fork location.

```
git push --mirror git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/org/new_project/fork_repo_name
```

---

To confirm all is in order.

Check in DevOps the History and you should see the copy of the fork in the new project matches with the original fork. Also, create a new PR and you should see that the upstream repo is the original repo as intended.